# react-redux how to show and hide nested element depends on parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to show and hide my child element depends on parent id. Assume if user click on parent id -> 1 then it should show all child element of parent id ->1. In my project I have lot of parent category and every parent category have lot of child category. I have an page where I am showing all of my main categories and sub-categories. But the problem if user click on parent category -> 1 then it's showing all child category from others parent category. see the screenshot [image]

here is my redux slicer code:

```
const { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } = require('@reduxjs/toolkit');

const STATUSES = Object.freeze(
    {
        IDLE: 'idle',
        ERROR: 'error',
        LOADING: 'loading'
    }
) 

const initialState = {
    categories: [],
    status: STATUSES.IDLE,


}

export const adsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ads_category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.categories = action.payload;
            
            state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
        });
},
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { ads_category, showcategory} = adsSlice.actions

export default adsSlice.reducer

// Thunks
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk('ads_category/fetch', async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/ads_category/');
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
});
```

here is my **page.js**

```
const PostAds = () => {
  const [showcat, setShowCat] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const show_data = useSelector(state=>state.ads)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
    
       }, []);
show_sub_category = ()=>{
        setShowCat(true)
       }
  
    return (
      <>
       {/*showing all of my main category */}
       {show_data.categories.map((data)=>(
              <button onClick={show_sub_category}> 
                   {data.main_category}
              </button>  
          
           {showcat &&
                 {/*showing all of my sub category */}
                 {data.sub_cat_bp.map((data)=>({data.sub-category}))}
            
           }
           
             

       ))}
```

here is my api data look like which getting fetching from redux:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to toggle multiple categories at the same time then i will suggest you to split your component to two pieces and then solving it becomes more easier. So you can do something like this

```js
const PostAds = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const adsList = useSelector((state) => state.ads);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* showing all of my main category */}
      {adsList.categories.map((category) => (
        <CategoryItem key={category.id} categoryData={category} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

And your CategoryItem should look like something this

```js
const CategoryItem = ({ categoryData }) => {
  const [isVisible, toggleVisibility] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => toggleVisibility(!isVisible)} type="button">
        {categoryData.name}
      </button>
      {isVisible &&
        categoryData.sub_cat_bp.map((info) => (
          <span key={info.id}>{info.sub_category}</span>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```